# Vector field on $S^2 \setminus \mathsf{NP}$ looks like a magnetic dipole

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

The following is a question from Spivak's Differential Geometry text:

[image]

Not really sure what he's going for here. Any ideas?

Comment: The easiest attempts at "combing the hairs on a ball", i.e. to construct an everywhere non-zero vector field on the sphere ends up with _two_ zero points. What he's getting at here is that it is possible to do it with just _one_ zero point. That being said, I think the arrows in the lower middle, pointing upwards should be pointing downwards.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed, it confused me that it seems like this vector field is continuous at $(0,0,1)$

Comment: It's continuous there, but not nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to explicitly construct such kind of vector field is to use the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) to transplant a constant vector field like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ from the $(x,y)$ plane.

Using the projection the sphere is parameterized as $$r(x,y)=(\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}, \frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2}, \frac{-1+x^2+y^2}{1+x^2+y^2})$$

Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is transplanted to 
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=2(\frac{1-x^2+y^2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}, -\frac{2xy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}, \frac{2x}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2})$$

This is the vector field you're looking for. To verify, note that 
$$\left\|\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right\|=\frac{2}{1+x^2+y^2}$$ which never vanish everywhere else except at $(0,0,1)$, corresponding to $(x,y)\rightarrow \infty$.